# AutoComplete in jQuery with dynamically added elements works only in first input field

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, autocomplete, typeahead.js

I have a scenario where when we load the page for the first time it will have an input field along with a button to add more rows. In my case, the autocomplete works on the very first row and it is not working on the rows added using the button.

The code is as follows

```js
  // In Js file

  $(".autocomplete").each((_, item) => {
    const $item = $(item);
    $item.typeahead(
      {
        minLength: 1,
        highlight: true,
      },
      {
        name: $item.attr("test-data"),
        source: async (keywords, syncResults, asyncResults) => {
          return $.ajax({
            data: { keywords: keywords },
            dataType: "json",
            success: (response) => {
              return asyncResults(response.items);
            },
            type: "post",
            url: window.URLS["autocomplete"][$item.attr("test-data")],
          });
        },
        limit: 10,
        templates: {
          notFound: "No match",
          pending: "Loading...",
          suggestion: (item) => {
            return `<div>${item}</div>`;
          },
        },
      },
    );
  });

// To handle add button click
$data.on("click", ".insert", () => {
    $data.append($(document.importNode($data.get(0).querySelector("template").content, true)));
});
```

```
// This is inside a twig file to add  a new input when the add button is clicked

<input
    class="autocomplete block"
    test-data="test"
    type="text"
    value="{{ value.event }}"
/>
```

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Most likely a common issue - your first input has an event listener attached, the following inputs don't because they are appended after the ```$(".autocomplete").each()``` has already finished running. You need to run the code again every time you append a new element. Plop it into a function and invoke it one on page load and once every time you create a new input.

Comment: If you don't mind how can I solve this? Can you give me the code for the above example? I have already spent 1 day on it. Thanks.

Comment: What plugin are you using? the jQueryUI one needs a .autocomplete.

Comment: @Shrimp  I have tried it in function. If I do it then it will have multiple input fields and CSS also broken

Ref: https://ibb.co/8gYJnmP

Comment: @mplungjan This one https://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/

Comment: I changed your tag. It was not the correct autocomplete

Answer (score 0):

You can have this

```
const atc = () => {    
  $(".autocomplete")
  .filter((_, item) => { return !$(item).is(".tt-input") }) // ignore already assigned autocompletes
  .each((_, item) => {
    const $item = $(item);
    ...
  });
}
```

and add

```
$(function() {
  $("#add")..on("click",() => {
     // add the field
     atc()
  });
  atc()
})
```

Comment: Thanks. But still, it has an unwanted input tag, which leads to broken CSS. How can I solve this?

Ref: https://ibb.co/pPcsLsf

Comment: I do not understand. Please post a [mcve]